# Decrypt segments in Host.processSegment

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I have my receiver app which plays encrypted HLS stream. With the KEY tag (EXT-X-KEY) in the manifest its able to play the encrypted content.But I want to decrypt the segments myself for some security issues, don't want to give the key url directly in the manifest.
    I used webcrypto to decrypt the HLS chunks. I tried that decrypt code (javascript) in Chrome browser it works fine.

**Problem**
  1) If I try to invoke the decrypt in host.processSegment() the Chromecast shows loading screen and then it hangs there and I need to reboot it every time.
  2) Even if I don't call decrypt and remove the EXT-X-KEY tag from manifest Chromecast hangs on loading.

In both the above case I don't see the Chromecast console logs printing my log statement from my decrypt() function. 
In all (regular playable state and hang state)   I see logs like

> [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET
>   http://192.168.x.x/mysites/movie_enc/hls-04-0.ts 200]
>   media_player.js:22 [  1.813s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0:
>   current=24153003.58, average=19741833.27 
> media_player.js:22 [  1.827s]
>   [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] 0: process segment
>   
> media_player.js:22 [  1.833s] [cast.player.hls.Adaptation] process
>   segment

I have been trying different things, for more than two weeks,  to make it work  working but to no-avail. Still looking for some solution.
Would really appreciate some pointers.
 
 I have modified my actual code to post in this forum.
 **Here is my code snippet.**

```js
sampleplayer.CastPlayer.prototype.decrypt = function(buf)
{
    this.log_("###---sampleplayer.CastPlayer.prototype.decrypt ");
    var castPlayerObj = this;
    var vector = castPlayerObj.getivArrayBuffer();
    var key = castPlayerObj.cryptoKeyObject;
   
    crypto.subtle.decrypt(  { name: 'AES-CBC', iv: vector } , key , buf).then(function (decrypted) {
            castPlayerObj.log_("###---Decrypt success.   ");
            return decrypted;
        },
        function(error){
            castPlayerObj.isDecrypting = false;
            castPlayerObj.log_("###---Decrypt failed ");
            castPlayerObj.log_(error.message);
            return buff;
        });    
};

sampleplayer.CastPlayer.prototype.load = function(){
 var host = new cast.player.api.Host({
        'url': url,
        'mediaElement': this.mediaElement_
      });

host.processSegment = function(streamIndex, data) {
        self.log_("prototype.loadVideo_::My.processSegment");
        self.log_("streamIndex= " + streamIndex);
        segmentCount++;
        self.log_("Segment count = " + segmentCount);
        self.log_("data length = " + data.length);
       
        
        self.log_("Decrypt stream segment ");
        return testDecrypt(data, key);*/
        
        //If I try to open this comment Chromecast hangs.
        //self.decrypt(data);
        
        return data;
    };


 this.player_ = new cast.player.api.Player(host);
};
```